# How does du calculate the size of a file in kilobytes?

Tags: du

I have a file for which
`du -b filename` gives `67108864` as the answer (which is supposed to be in bytes),
while
`du filename` gives `65604` (which is supposed to be in kilobytes).
However, it should return `67108864/1024 = 65536` as the answer.

I looked at the man entry for `du`, but couldn't find the answer.
What am I missing?

I'm running Ubuntu version 12.04 on a 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 6):

`-b` is not just bytes:

> ```
>   -b, --bytes           equivalent to `--apparent-size --block-size=1'
>   --apparent-size   print apparent sizes, rather than disk usage; although
>                       the apparent size is usually smaller, it may be
>                       larger due to holes in (`sparse') files, internal
>                       fragmentation, indirect blocks, and the like
> ```

Comment: Thanks so much. Therefore logically, I hope it is perfectly fine to treat it as a file with 67108864 bytes, and no more?

Comment: I suppose that depends on what you're doing with it. If you're calculating how big of a hard drive you need, you'd better use `65604*1024`. If you want to know how many bytes you can read from the file, that would be `67108864`

Comment: Yes, the latter. Thanks again.